# SupportMapFragment issue

Tags: android

Why i have not access to some static content in support fragment ?
please see my codes

```
Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(MapFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

and

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment 
{
    protected View originalContentView;
    protected MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        originalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mapWrapperLayout = new MapWrapperLayout(RContextHelper.getActivity());
        mapWrapperLayout.addView(originalContentView);
        return mapWrapperLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }

}
```

MapFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER saying **ARG_PLANET_NUMBER cannot be resolved or is not a field**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please initialize the static variable `ARG_PLANET_NUMBER` in `MapFragment` class. for example,

```
 public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment 
{
    //initialize this variable
    public static int ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = 1;

    protected View originalContentView;
    protected MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        originalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mapWrapperLayout = new MapWrapperLayout(RContextHelper.getActivity());
        mapWrapperLayout.addView(originalContentView);
        return mapWrapperLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }

}
```

Comment: I thought ARG_PLANET_NUMBER  is part of Fragment class ,sorry.thanks for reply